# Why does spotlight search for "term" result in AquaTerm before Terminal?

Tags: spotlight

I have AquaTerm and Terminal both.

Whenever I do a search in the spotlight with query "term" it shows up AquaTerm before Terminal. Terminal matches better, so it should come first.

Why does spotlight search for "term" result in AquaTerm before Terminal?

Comment: My guess would be that capitalization considered, AquaTerm contains the exact whole word "term", while it's only a fragment of the word "Terminal". Then again, I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, so it would always be speculation.

Comment: That does not explain why iTerm is ranked third. here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/geRuh.png. I guess we would never know :(

Comment: Yes, iStuff does not seem to follow that logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For Spotlight there isn't really a difference between AquaTerm, Terminal and iTerm when searching for "term". All three names match the search term, there is no such notion as *better*
- Spotlight "learns" your preferences over time. So if you keep searching for "term" and then always select "Terminal.app" as result it will reorder the result list over time